# How do I resize xna window without GraphicsDevice?

Tags: c#, xna, resize

Ok I have a `Scene` class which basically looks like this:

```
public class Scene : DrawableGameComponent
{
  public List<GameComponent> SceneComponents { get; set; }
    public Scene(Game game)
        : base(game)
    {
        SceneComponents = new List<GameComponent>();
}
```

Then got my `Scene1` class which looks like this:

```
public class Scene1 : Scene
{
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;        
    private Game game;

    public Scene1(Game game) : base(game)
    {
        this.game = game;
        spriteBatch = (SpriteBatch)game.Services.GetService(typeof(SpriteBatch));
   }
}
```

And I got the `Game1` class which looks like this:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Scene1 scene1;
    //Scene2 scene2;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }
}
```

Now obviously they are much larger than that but I just wanted the signatures and extensions.

All the game does is running scenes....the scene class doesn't matter.

I am working on `Scene1` and would like to change the screen resolution to 500x500 any idea how I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You already have `GraphicsDevice` component, because your class inherits from `DrawableGameComponent`, so if you need it you simply use `Game.GraphicsDevice`.